# How to search a file in subdirectories?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have to create a program that search the file "letter.txt" in the subdirectories of a specific directory ( folderA in the example below ).

For example:

```
folderA/
   folderA1/...
   folderA2/...
   folderA3/...
   folderA4/letter.txt
   folderA5/...
```

What API do I have to use to:

```
- list subdirectories of a specific directory ( folderA ), 
- open each of these subdirectories ( folderA1, folderA2, folderA3, etc ) 
- search and open the file letter.txt ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In raw Win32, this would be done using [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but you will have to code the recursion manually; it's going to be hard to get all the corner cases right (e.g. what happens if you have reparse points that create a cyclic directory structure?).

For more convenience you can use `Boost.Filesystem`; class [`recursive_directory_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#Class-recursive_directory_iterator) does exactly what you want. In the past I have also used the [recls library](http://synesis.com.au/software/recls/) and I was quite satisfied -- it just works.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I know how to do that task is to use the Boost.filesystem library.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm

It provides a directory iterator (and a recursive directory iterator) that allows you to iterate through files and directories in your directory looking for the file you need need.